# phpunit is not working: "src/TextUI/Command.php"

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-2.0, vagrant

I have `cakePHP-2.0` in vagrant on `ubuntu-12.04` and `phpunit-3.7.*`.

When I try to run the test, it shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'src/TextUI/Command.php' (include_path='/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/php-timer:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/Vendor/symfony/yaml:/home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/vagrant/test-phpunit/cakePHP-2.0/app/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteCommand.php on line 21
```

Comment: which test you run, show us the command, also paste the `Vagrantfile`

Comment: The `vendor` folder is in small letters. Try `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoloaders.

Answer (score 2):

Try append following line to APP/Config/bootstrap.php.
It works for me (CakePHP 2.6.1 using Composer.)

```
define('__PHPUNIT_PHAR__', '');
```